# Login and show menu items by if

Tags: python, tkinter, authentication, menubar

I'm trying to create a login with a tkinter Entry.
Compare the input with the password and if it is correct you are supposed to get access to more stuff in the menu bar.

If I understand correctly I need to update the window in order for the menu to update, but I cant figure out how.
And the variable "moberg" don't seems to update to True. Might be that one is global(?) and the other one belongs to a class. But I cant figure out how to make that work either.

Here is a sample of what I've done so far.

```
from tkinter import *
moberg="no"
class PCMsyntax(Frame):
    def update():
        print("updated") #only for visual, remove later
        app.mainloop.after(1, update)

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)
        syntaxMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        submenu = Menu(syntaxMenu)
        syntaxMenu.add_cascade(label='Arithmetic Exp', underline=0, command='')
        syntaxMenu.add_cascade(label='Assign & Compare', underline=0, command='')
        syntaxMenu.add_separator()
        syntaxMenu.add_cascade(label='Math', menu=submenu, underline=0)
        submenu.add_command(label="abs()", command='')
        if moberg == True:
            syntaxMenu.add_cascade(label='No public access', menu=submenu, underline=0)
            submenu.add_command(label="onlyForLabTech()")



        menubar.add_cascade(label="Syntax", underline=0, menu=syntaxMenu)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Login", underline=0, command=self.onLogin)


    def onLogin(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Password(self.newWindow)



class Password():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.pwd = Entry(self.master, width=30, bg="whitesmoke", foreground="whitesmoke")
        self.pwd.pack()
        self.verifyButton = Button(self.frame, text = 'Verify', width = 25, command = self.verify_password)
        self.verifyButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def verify_password(self):
        user_entry = self.pwd.get() 
        if str(user_entry) == "test":
            moberg=True
            print(moberg) #only for visual, remove later
            PCMsyntax.update
            self.master.destroy()
        else:
            moberg=False
            print(moberg) #only for visual, remove later
            self.master.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("560x600")
    app = PCMsyntax(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you created a [mcve]. There's a lot of code unrelated to the problem. All you need is the entry fields and perhaps a couple menu item to configure after login.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I have removed the stuff that is irrelevant.

Comment: So what exactly is it you are trying to do? The user loads your program, all they see is an entry box, they enter a password, if the password is right then the real program loads?

Comment: No, they see the menu and the program, but if they login I'll like to show more options in the menubar.

Comment: @Guinness Have you considered that an easy way to do this could be to have two frames in your window. One visible and packed with all of your non login menu items. The other hidden and containing all of your login details. When the user logins (probably through a Toplevel which draws as the result of a menubar command) you could then draw the second frame.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that I dont understand. But it sounds good. I have to admit, I started with python like 4 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve something like what you're looking for with the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.public = Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid") #public, visible frame
        self.hidden = Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid") #hidden, private frame
        self.label1 = Label(self.public, text="This text and everything over here is public.") #this is inside the public frame and so is visible
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.public) #so is this
        self.label2 = Label(self.hidden, text="This text and everything over here is hidden and only appears after login.") #this one is in the hidden frame and so is private before login
        self.button1 = Button(self.public, text="Login", command=self.command) #this is in the public frame
        self.public.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both") #we pack the public frame on the left of the window
        self.label1.pack() #then we pack all the widgets for both frames here and below
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
    def command(self): #whenever the login button is pressed this is called
        if self.button1.cget("text") == "Login" and self.entry1.get() == "password": #we check if the button is in login state or not and if the password is correct
            self.hidden.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both") #if it is we pack the hidden frame which makes it and it's contents visible
            self.button1.configure({"text": "Logout"}) #we then set the button to a logout state
        elif self.button1.cget("text") == "Logout": #if the button is in logout state
            self.hidden.pack_forget() #we pack_forget the frame, which removes it and it's contents from view
            self.button1.configure({"text": "Login"}) #and then we set the button to login state

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is fairly self explanatory and where it isn't I've explained what's happening.

This is just one way of many of achieving what it is you're looking for.

I'd also like to point out that login systems are complicated and if you're looking to use this for anything serious or as a package to sell then the way I have done this is not secure.

I'd recommend looking at other ways people handle sensitive information in tkinter.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I will play around with your example,

Comment: @Guinness If this answers your question, please can you mark this as accepted for future users.